# Create session in gridview cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i have a gridview with  tempaltefield buttons,
i want to create a session with value of a cell in selected button row ,
can anyone help me i tryed this but didnt work:

```
    protected void ImageButton1_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
    Session["mysession"] = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error / exception?

Comment: yes :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Make sure GridView1.SelectedRow is not null.

Comment: can i use : Session["mysession"] = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["Id"].ToString();    or not?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if it's just a imagebutton in a templatefield, actually you don't select de row. This line will problably throw an exception because SelectedRow is null.
But if you are using a command to select, that's correct. Maybe your event (ImageButton1_Click1) is not assigned to your image (OnClick).

You can try something like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Add and event RowDataBound
            grvGrid.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(grvGrid_RowDataBound); 
        }
        catch
        {
            //...throw
        }
    }

    protected void grvGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                //...
            }

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {          
                //Add an ImageButton foreach row in GridView
                ImageButton ibtImageAlt = new ImageButton();
                ibtImageAlt.ImageUrl = "App_Images/y.gif";

                //ImageButton's ID will be the index of the row
                ibtImageAlt.ID = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();                    
                ibtImageAlt.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                ibtImageAlt.Font.Overline = false;
                ibtImageAlt.Click += ibtImageAlt_Click;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        //...throw
        }
    }

    protected void ibtImageAlt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Catch the ImageButton ID and the row in GridView

            //An example to catch the value of the row selected by the ImageButton
            Int32 intIndexRow = Convert.ToInt32(((ImageButton)sender).ID);
            String strTest = grvGrid.Rows[intIndexRow].Cells[0].Text;
        }
        catch
        {
            //...throw
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have do a mistake it not a imagebutton, but more any imagebutton is assigned  to a row of gridview

Comment: (ImageButton1_Click1)  is assigned ,because it work for the other sessions.

Comment: Yes, you can use Session["mysession"] = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["Id"].Value.ToString();. But make sure you have grv.DataKeysNames assign to the id of your field.
                IE: DataKeysNames="Id"
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" Visible="False" HeaderText="IdPeriodo" SortExpression="IdPeriodo" />. And don't forget to include ".value" before the "toString()".

Comment: ok ,but RowIndex show me error : does not contain a definition... :(

Comment: I can only use the "e" if you are in a method of your GridView, like RowDataBound. In your case, you are in a method of an ImageButton, so you won't have access to GridView Args, only the ImageClick Args. You can use ((ImageButton)sender).xxx where xxx is the properties of your ImageButton that you have clicked, if that helps.

Comment: Thank you! We are here to get helped and help too! Don't forget to mark. Good luck!